# Oil Drum Fire Overspill

Tags: collision, fire

Even though I have collisions turned on I seem to get overspill from the flames and smoke

[image: See image for overspill]

Comment: I wonder if the barrel is not manifold. You could do a mesh cleanup as these guys explain: [ALL3DP](https://all3dp.com/2/blender-simplify-mesh-simply-explained/).

Comment: It was indeed, thank you for your help.